# Checking defined item in enum

Tags: javascript, enums

I have an enum in which I store some UI element values that look like this:

```
const uiElementAttributes = {
   1: {
      id: 1,
      color: 'red',
      icon: 'icon-something.png'
   },
   2: {
      id: 2,
      color: 'yellow',
      icon: 'icon-something-else.png'
   },
   3: {
      id: 3,
      color: 'blue',
      icon: 'icon-this-item.png'
   },
   99: {
      id: 99,
      color: 'black',
      icon: 'icon-black.png'
   }
};
```

I have a function that will return the correct object from the enum based on id passed to my function. My question is how do I check if a value is defined in an enum?

Here's the function:

```
const getAttributes (id) => {

   // How do I check to see if the id is in the enum?
   if(checkIfIdIsInEnum) {
      return uiElementAttributes[id];
   } else {
      return uiElementAttributes[99];
   }

};
```

UPDATE: I'm trying the suggested answer. It does look pretty straight forward but looks like when webpack transpiles my code to vanilla JS, it adds `default` at the end of my `enum` which is `undefined`. Any idea what may be causing this -- see below? As you can see, the `id` value I'm passing is `1` so it should be able to find the value 1 in my enum object.

[image]

And here's the actual `enum` object:
[image]

Here's the actual function code: 
[image]

UPDATE 2:
I resolved the issue by importing the enum within curly braces -- see below:

```
import {calendarEvents} from '../../enums/calendarEvents';
```

Comment: So `if(uiElementAttributes.hasOwnProperty(id)){ /*it exists*/}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this special case, you could access the property and if the result is falsey, then take the default property `99`.

```
const getAttributes = id => uiElementAttributes[id] || uiElementAttributes[99];
```

Otherwise, you could use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in), or the suggested [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Comment: I'm using this suggested solution which seems pretty straight forward but I'm getting an error. Please see the UPDATE I've added to the original post.

Comment: it depends on the data structure, which is not viewable at the image.

Comment: Just updated the original post with a screen shot of the `enum` object.

Comment: In the actual code, my default value will come from object 0.

Comment: i see `calendarEvents` and not `calendarEvents2` without any default property.

Comment: Not sure why it becomes `calendarEvents2`. I just posted the actual code of the function.

Comment: Looks like the `default` is what's messing things up. Not sure why my `enum` object gets renamed to `CalendarEvents2` and `default` is appended to the name.

Comment: i have no idea either.

Comment: I resolved it. See UPDATE 2. Thank you for your help!